# scroll to the top of the page (doesnt work in chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a ui theme called [nightsky](http://www.nightskyadmin.com/demo/template/dashboard.html)

After I scroll to the bottom of the page I want to go back to the top of the page.

I want a single line command that can be executed in console not a jsfiddle.

What I have tried already in dev console :

1. `window.scrollTo(0, $("body").offset().top);`
2. `window.scrollTo(0, $("#main").offset().top();`
3. The following:

   ```
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('#main').position().top },
       1000
   );
   ```

   seems to work in firefox not in chrome
4. `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0});`

I am looking for a code that can be executed in console! no on-click listeners etc...just few lines of code

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0, $("body").offset().top)` this works, just tried it. you can also try `window.scrollTo(0, $(document).top)`

Comment: Number 3. should work fine also in chrome, if not there might be some markup problems or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#header')[0].scrollIntoView()
```

Comment: Thankyou - someone actually read the question and tried it on the template link.  Good idea too - I tried everything I could think of and couldn't see why the normal methods don't work.

Comment: I'm guessing one of the many included scripts is overriding regular scroll methods for some reason.  It's a bit naughty.

Comment: @Archer `window.scrollTo` is not overwritten. Just print it out in the console you will see `function scrollTo() { [native code] }`.

Comment: Yeah, I know but something's obviously going on as none of the regular scroll methods work

Comment: I think the issue is in the markup but it would take a long time to debug.

Comment: @Gpx is this cross browser compatible. is there any side effects of using this. haven't seen this function ever

Comment: @TabraizAli I'm assuming that you're using jQuery. The method `scrollIntoView` is supported even by IE6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView

Answer (score 1):

I think the plugin [sliderNav](http://devgrow.com/slidernav/) used on the theme replaces the scrollbars, that's why regular scrolling methods don't work.

Try this (gets the first element in your body to show):

```
$('body')[0].firstElementChild.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Have a +1 .  Nice use of `firstElementChild` - I like defensive programming!

Answer (score -3):

You Can Just Use This Code

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>

<a href="#main">Main</a>



<div id="home">
    long Text ........
</div>

<div id="main">
    long Text ........
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and The Page will Have smooth scroll